# How can I extend this command to take more arguments

Tags: arguments, latex

I have this command (createPerson) that already takes 9 arguments. However, I need it to take more. I have read on the xargs package but I cannot figure out how to use it. Can you help me to apply the changes to the method or maybe propose a better solution. My minimum working code is like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}           % Til tabeller der tilpaser sig i bredden
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}r}

\usepackage{xifthen}            % Used to test if an argument is empty
\usepackage{datetime}           % Used to format dates
\newdateformat{timeLineDate}{\THEDAY.~\shortmonthname~\THEYEAR}
\newdateformat{monthYearDate}{\monthname[\THEMONTH]~\THEYEAR}

%Arguments: 
%   1) MANDATORY    - Reference to the current full name
%   2) OPTIONAL     - Full birth name
%   3) MANDATORY    - Called name
%   4) MANDATORY    - Birth date in the format of dd. mmm. yyyy
%       4)              - Day
%       5)              - Month
%       6)              - Year
%   7) OPTIONAL     - Death date in the format of dd. mmm. yyyy
%       7)              - Day
%       8)              - Month
%       9)              - Year
\newcommand{\createPerson}[9]
{
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXRc}%
            Navn:   &   \nameref{#1}  &   \formatdate{#4}{#5}{#6} &   $\star$\\%
            \ifNoArgumentElse{#2}{Kaldenavn:    &   #3}{Fødenavn:   &   #2} &   \ifNoArgumentElse{#7#8#9}{&}{%
                \ifNoArgumentElse{#7}{%
                    \ifNoArgumentElse{#8}{#9}{\monthYearDate\formatdate{1}{#8}{#9}}%
                }{\formatdate{#7}{#8}{#9}} & \cross%
            }%
            \ifNoArgumentElse{#2}{}{\\Kaldenavn: & #3 &&}%
        \end{tabularx}%
}

%Arguments
%   1) The argument to test
%   2) If empty then do this
%   3) If not empty then do this
\newcommand{\ifNoArgumentElse}[3]{
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{#2}{#3}%
}

\newcommand{\cross}[1][1pt]{\ooalign{%
  \rule[1ex]{1ex}{#1}\cr% Horizontal bar
  \hss\rule{#1}{.7em}\hss\cr}% Vertical bar
}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Else Jensen}
\label{person1}

\createPerson
    {person1}
    {Else Nielsen}
    {Else}
    {11}
    {9}
    {1940}
    {13}
    {11}
    {1999}


\subsection{Hans Wright}
\label{person2}

\createPerson
    {person2}
    {}
    {Hans}
    {11}
    {9}
    {1940}
    {}
    {11}
    {1999}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2132/15925

Comment: @AndrewSwann Can you give an example of how to declare and access/use the variables?